# Split String with .(dot) character java android

Tags: java, android, split

Hello friends i have string like

```
Android_a_b.pdf
```

i want to split it like `Android_a_b` and `pdf`

i try following code like

```
String s="Android_a_b.pdf"; 
String[] parts = s.split(".");
String part1 = parts[0];  
String part2 = parts[1];
```

when i run above code it give me error like

```
11-05 09:42:28.922: E/AndroidRuntime(8722): Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=0; index=0
```

at `String part1 = parts[0];` line

any idea how can i solve it?

Answer (score 85, accepted):

You need to escape `.` using `\`

Eg:

```
String s="Android_a_b.pdf";
String[] parts = s.split("\\."); // escape .
String part1 = parts[0];
String part2 = parts[1];
```

Now it will split by `.`

[Split(regex)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) in `Java`

> Splits this string around matches of the given **regular expression**.
>
> This method works as if by invoking the two-argument split method with
>   the given expression and a limit argument of zero. Trailing empty
>   strings are therefore not included in the resulting array.

Keep in mind that

> Parameters:
>       regex - the delimiting regular expression

Comment: It's also important to note that your error points out there is nothing in your Array.  If you try to access [0] and get an index out of bounds then you can safely assume that there is something wrong with the split.

Comment: Exactly. Unescaped, the `"."` matches every character, so every character is a delimiter and the result of the split consists entirely of empty strings, none of which are included in the return value.

Comment: Pattern.quote will make your life easier: s.split(Pattern.quote(".")); (use import java.util.regex.Pattern)

Comment: When we have a input like "12.34..." split length is still 2. But if we have "12.34...5" split length is 5. Seems like when a number ends with more dot, that is not considered. But in my case I need that to be considered in length. Any Idea?